# geolocalization in views filter proximity

Tags: location, i18n-l10n

I wants to get the coordinates in proximity filter on views in location module, so i also wants to use the html5 and not a ip localization.

I found [this patch](http://drupal.org/files/issues/820116-location-3.1-geoip-views.patch) that i can fast change, but i wants now to obtain the position with html5 and save it in  $geoip_location->latitude; (in this example). How can i get the longitude and latitude of the anonymous user and use it in lcoation proximity filter in views (that only allow php)?

Thanks